# Apache Alias to Network-share which can be Offline during startup

Tags: apache

I'm trying to map a Network share with an alias into my http path.
All works fine, but I do have the Problem, that my Networkshare can be inaccessible during Apache startup. Actually Apache hangs during Startup. Is there a Option that let Apache ignore the not available Network share, so that Apache tries to connect on every Access...

Here is my conf:

```
Alias /e //10.15.228.3/e
<Directory "//10.15.228.3/e">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All is running under Windows with Apache 2.4.

THANX!